# Erro executar uma chamada telefônica

Tags: android

O erro aparece quando clico no botão CHAMAR TELEFONE.

Classe MainActivity

```
package com.edu.chamada;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnChamar;
    Button btnTelefone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnChamar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChamar);
        btnTelefone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTelefone);

        btnChamar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com.br");

                Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                startActivity(it);
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnTelefone.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("34621026");

                Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);


                iniciarTelefone(it);
            }
        });
    }
    public void iniciarTelefone(Intent it){
        startActivity(it);
        finish();
    }

    //Criar um menu da aplicação


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.acaoTelefonar){
            Log.i("Saida do Menu", "Você escolheu: "+ id);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.edu.chamada.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnChamar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/btnChamar"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnTelefone"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnChamar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChamar"
        android:text="@string/btnTelefone"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ERRO

```
05-31 14:28:39.017 2103-2103/com.mantovani.projetotelefone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.mantovani.projetotelefone, PID: 2103
                                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL }
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
                                                                                 at com.mantovani.projetotelefone.MainActivity.iniciarTelefone(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                 at com.mantovani.projetotelefone.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


                                                                             [ 05-31 14:28:39.027  1567: 1688 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8f012a0, tid 1688
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código que constrói o intent para iniciar o discador está errado. Deveria ser assim:

```
    Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    it.setData(Uri.parse("tel:34621026"));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        iniciarTelefone(it);
    }
```

Outra coisa, por que você chama o finish() depois de iniciar o intent. Isso vai encerrar o aplicativo. É prá fazer isso mesmo?

Comment: qual a diferença 'Intent.ACTION_DIAL' do 'Intent.ACTION_CALL'

Comment: o erro só estava na sintaxe onde tinha que colocar o "tel:" valeu.

Comment: Você não estava passando a Uri com o telefone para o intent no seu código (com o setData) nem checando se o disposivo possui meios de fazer uma ligação (por exemplo, se for um tablet, seu app vai crashear). O ACTION_CALL faz a chamada diretamente sem a intervenção do usuário (mas requer que sejam dadas as devidas permissões pra isso) o ACTION_DIAL apenas mostra o discador, mas com o número já setado para o usuário confirmar e discar, e isso não requer permissões especiais no aplicativo.